# I want to generate an CaseID using city name, sector id and auto incremental value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, auto-increment

I want to generate an Case ID using city name sector number and auto incremental value. I am able to generate CaseID like if City name is Mumbai and Sector is 04 then it will generate Mum04 after that i want an auto incremental number. I am using mongoDB as database

I have tried to get Case ID like Mum04 where `Mum = Mumbai(city name)` and 04 is sector.

```
import pymongo
from datetime import date
import datetime

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["KeyGen"]
mycol = mydb["primary_key_test"]

## GET LAST RECORD ID
last_record_id = 0
for x in mycol.find():
  last_record_id = x['_id']

## GET LAST RECORD PRIMARY KEY
last_record = mycol.find_one({'_id':last_record_id})
last_record_pk = last_record['primary_key']

## Get LAST RECORD COUNTER
counter = last_record_pk[6:]

## GET MONTH AND YEAR
city = input('Enter City Name: ')
sector = input('Enter your City Sector ')
citycode = (city[0:3])

## INSERT NEW DOCUMENT
new_counter= int(counter)+1
new_counter1 = '{0:04d}'.format(new_counter)
new_primary_key = citycode+sector+new_counter1
mycol.insert_one({'primary_key':new_primary_key})
```

I want to generate Case ID like `Mum-04-0001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like 0001 or 0002 (leading zero) than you can use zfill()

```
num = str(1).zfill(4)
o/p> 0001
num = str(999).zfill(4)
o/p> 0999

caseid = 'Mum-04' + '-' + num
```

is this what you are looking? Sorry if i get it wrong...

Comment: Ya it worked ! but i need to point to the last entry submitted to the database. thank you very much..!